# Meu scanf não está guardando o valor recebido pelo teclado e eu não sei mais o que fazer

Tags: c++, scanf

Então... estou tentando usar estruturas com ponteiro e fazer funções comandadas por arquivos diferentes. No arquivo "main" eu só faço chamar as funções e receber o "return" de cada uma.
Eu estou fazendo uma função insere, que insere valores dentro de uma lista duplamente encadeado que segura uma estrutura Aluno com informações de cada aluno, como por exemplo Nome e Notas.

eu chamo a função assim: l = lst_insere(l);

e a função é assim: (apenas código agora e comentários)

```
struct aluno
{
    char nome[81];
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
};
typedef struct aluno Aluno;

struct lista2
{
    Aluno *info;
    struct lista2* ant;
    struct lista2* prox;
};
typedef struct lista2 Lista2; 

Lista2* lst_insere (Lista2* l)
{
    Lista2* novo1=(Lista2 *)malloc(sizeof(Lista2)); /*eu reservo um espaço de memória pra Lista2*/
    Aluno* novo2=(Aluno *)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));    /*aqui eu reservo pra Aluno*/
    novo1->info = novo2;                            /*e aqui eu faço a união das duas*/
    
    printf("\n\nNome do aluno:\n");
    fflush(stdin);     //o fflush foi usado na função inteira pra resolver outro problema no "run"
    scanf(" %[^\n]", novo1->info->nome);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\nPrimeira nota do aluno:\n");
    printf("valor antes de perguntar o valor %.2f\n", novo1->info->nota1);
    /* esse print aqui eu fiz pra saber o que estava ocorrendo durante o processo de run da do arquivo main, e o valor que já estava em cada um não foi alterado pelo próximo scanf */

scanf("%.2f", &novo1->info->nota1);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\nSegunda nota do aluno:\n");
printf("valor antes de perguntar o valor %.2f\n", novo1->info->nota2);
/*o mesmo aconteceu aqui, já existia um valor no campo nota2 e não foi alterado pelo próximo scanf*/

scanf("%.2f", &novo1->info->nota2);
fflush(stdin);

novo1->prox = l;   //aqui eu faço o prox apontar para o endereço de memória de l e juntar os 2
novo1->ant = NULL; //faço ant ser NULL, pq para inserir na lista sempre a esquerda não há nada
/*  verifica se lista não está vazia    */
/*  e aponta para novo1 em ant          */
if (l != NULL)
{
    l->ant = novo1;  //faz apontar para o novo elemento da lista
}
return novo1;
```

}'"

Answer (score 0):

quando você tenta ler os valores float, usou uma mascara para pegar só dois dígitos após a virgula. Mas como você ja esta usando elas também no print f, não a necessidade. Alias, isso causa o problema relatado.

use só o %f

```
scanf("%f", &novo1->info->nota1);
```

Se quiser delimitar a quantidade dígitos, é preciso de outra abordagem.

Answer (score 0):

Habilite SEMPRE as mensagens de erro de seu compilador.

Veja a saída ao compilar seu programa

```
or3.c(40): warning C4476: 'scanf' : unknown type field
or3 character '.' in format specifier
or3.c(40): warning C4474: 'scanf' : too many arguments passed\
 for format string
or3.c(40): note: placeholders and their parameters expect 0\
 variadic arguments, but 1 were provided
or3.c(48): warning C4476: 'scanf' : unknown type field\
 character '.' in format specifier
or3.c(48): warning C4474: 'scanf' : too many arguments\
 passed for format string
or3.c(48): note: placeholders and their parameters\
 expect 0 variadic arguments, but 1 were provided
or3.c(21): fatal error C1075: '{': no matching token found
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

[image: E veja o que tem nessas linhas]

Veja no manual que `scanf()` não tem esse formato para ler `float/double`

#### Exemplo

O programa (código a seguir) lê o valor do especificador a ser usado com `scanf` e depois tenta ler um `float`. Rode e verá o efeito de cada opção. no geral é possível limitar o tamanho dos campos com um parâmetro que vem imediatamente depois do `%`. O tamanho do campo e não a posição do ponto decimal.

```
Digite a mascara a ser usada para ler float via scanf() [ex. "%f"]



Especificador: %f
Valor: 1234.5678
Especificador: "%f" Valor (com %10.5f) = 1234.56775

Especificador: %7f
Valor: 1234.5678
Especificador: "%7f" Valor (com %10.5f) = 1234.56006

Especificador: %6f
Valor: 1234.5678
Especificador: "%6f" Valor (com %10.5f) = 1234.50000

Especificador: %4f
Valor: 1234.5678
Especificador: "%4f" Valor (com %10.5f) = 1234.00000

Especificador: %2f
Valor: 1234.5678
Especificador: "%2f" Valor (com %10.5f) =   12.00000

Especificador: x
Valor: x
```

Veja que com `1234.5678` `%7f` lê `1234.56` e `%2f` lê apenas 12. Com `%4f` lê, como esperado, apenas `1234`. E entenda que TODO o resto fica no buffer para ser lido.

#### o código

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    float x = 0.;
    int   res = 1;
    char  mask[20];
    puts(
        "Digite a mascara a ser usada"
        " para ler float via scanf() "
        "[ex. \"%f\"]\n\n");
    while (res > 0)
    { 
        printf("\nEspecificador: ");
        if (fgets(mask, 20, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
        mask[strlen(mask) - 1] = 0;
        printf("Valor: ");
        res = scanf(mask, &x);
        if (res != 1) return -2;
        printf("Especificador: \"%s\" Valor (com %%10.5f) = %10.5f\n", mask,x);
        fgets(mask, 20, stdin); // consome o resto da linha
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Não use `fflush()` na entrada. Sequer está definida essa função para streams de entrada. Apenas consuma os dados corretamente.